# using random to choose a function to run (50/50 chance needed)

Tags: python

code being run(apart from modules and functions)

```
random.choice(frontright(),frontleft())
```

error raised:

```
TypeError: Random.choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice You called the functions, instead of passing them. Also you didn't put them in a collection.

Comment: The error message that you posted does not match the example code.

Comment: `frontright()` and `frontleft()` are function _calls_: this calls _both_ functions first and then passes their return values to `random.choice`. It doesn't "choose a function to run".

Answer (score 4):

random.choice expects a sequence to choose from. That's not what you passed it.

Functions are objects, so you can put them in a sequence and then choose from that. But if you use parens you aren't using the function itself; you are actually calling all of the functions, then passing their return values to random.choice

This code might demonstrate the difference.

```
import random

def frontright():
    print ('frontright was called')
    return 'frontright result'

def frontleft():
    print ('frontleft was called')
    return 'frontleft result'

my_functions = (frontright, frontleft)
fn = random.choice(my_functions)
print('calling one function')
fn()

print()
print('collection of results')
my_choice = random.choice((frontright(), frontleft()))
print('chosen result was:', my_choice)
```

You're actually passing 2 when it expects 1 sequence, but internally it is calling an instance method, and at that point it's really 3 instead of 2, if you include self.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to do this `random.choice([frontright(), frontleft()])`

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choice.asp

Comment: Note that this "answer" answers the question that is not asked in the question... Please clarify what you are answering... and ideally explain why OP got the error message with the code they shown.

Comment: @Br3xin note that this has the problem of calling **both** functions before making a choice.